# I get an error when I load a tensorflow2.0 model

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I am learning a simple model to perform a linear regression and then I save the model

```
class NN(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super(NN, self).__init__()
    L = 20
    self.W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random.truncated_normal([1, L], stddev=math.sqrt(3)))
    self.B1 = tf.Variable(tf.random.truncated_normal([1, L], stddev=1.0))
    self.W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random.truncated_normal([L, 1], stddev=math.sqrt(3/L)))
    self.B2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
  def call(self, inputs):
    Z1 = tf.matmul(inputs, self.W1) + self.B1
    Y1 = tf.nn.tanh(Z1)
    Y = tf.matmul(Y1, self.W2) + self.B2
    return Y

# The loss function to be optimized
def loss(model, X, Y_):
  error = model(X) - Y_
  return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(error))

model = NN()
optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
bsize = 20

# You can call this function in a loop to train the model, bsize samples at a time
def training_step(i):
  # read data
  x_batch, y_batch = func.next_batch(bsize)
  x_batch = np.reshape(x_batch, (bsize,1))
  y_batch = np.reshape(y_batch, (bsize,1))
  # compute training values
  loss_fn = lambda: loss(model, x_batch, y_batch)
  optimizer.minimize(loss_fn, [model.W1, model.B1, model.W2, model.B2])
  if i%5000 == 0:
    l = loss(model, x_batch, y_batch)
    print(str(i) + ": epoch: " + str(func._epochs_completed) + ": loss: " + str(l.numpy()))

for i in range(50001): 
  training_step(i)

# save the model
tf.saved_model.save(model, "my_file")
```

and then I am trying to load the model with the following lines following tensorflow documentation:

```
model = tf.saved_model.load("my_file")
f = model.signatures["serving_default"]
y = f(x)
```

However I get the following error message:

```
 f = model.signatures["serving_default"]
File "my_file/signature_serialization.py", line 195, in __getitem__
    return self._signatures[key]
KeyError: 'serving_default'
```

What is wrong ? Why serving_default is not defined ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding a third argument to the tf.saved_model.save function

```
tf.saved_model.save(model, "myfile", signatures=model.call.get_concrete_function(tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None,1], dtype=tf.float32, name="inp")))
```

and by adding the @tf.function above the call method

```
class NN(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super(NN, self).__init__()
    L = 20
    self.W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random.truncated_normal([1, L], stddev=math.sqrt(3)))
    self.B1 = tf.Variable(tf.random.truncated_normal([1, L], stddev=1.0))
    self.W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random.truncated_normal([L, 1], stddev=math.sqrt(3/L)))
    self.B2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
  @tf.function
  def call(self, X):
    Z1 = tf.matmul(X, self.W1) + self.B1
    Y1 = tf.nn.tanh(Z1)
    Y = tf.matmul(Y1, self.W2) + self.B2
    return Y
```